# Access LinkedIn Profile with Python

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I am trying to computationally access my own LinkedIn profile via API to download my own posts. There are three recent Python wrappers to access my profile, e.g. [linkedin-sdk](https://pypi.org/project/linkedin-sdk/), [pawl](https://pypi.org/project/linkedin-sdk/), [LinkedIn V2](https://pypi.org/project/python-linkedin-v2/). However, I have been unable to make them work. The problem is the authentication. I have seen the famous [LinkedIn-API wrapper](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin), but its authentication process is [complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481272/python-linkedin-api-how-do-i-use-it?rq=1) and [difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195121/accessing-linkedin-data-via-api-using-python-and-authorisation-in-general/51227374#51227374) probably due to LinkedIn changing its authentication process and access scope.

Based on [this tutorial from last year](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mining-social-media-data-using-python-2-make-api-request-wong/) I have been able to access my own profile to view my name, country, language and id.

```
import requests

#get access_token by post with user & password
#Step 1 - GET to request for authentication
def get_auth_link():
    URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization"
    client_id= 'XXXX'
    redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/login'
    scope='r_liteprofile'
    PARAMS = {'response_type':'code', 'client_id':client_id,  'redirect_uri':redirect_uri, 'scope':scope}
    r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
    return_url = r.url
    print('Please copy the URL and paste it in browser for getting authentication code')
    print('')
    print(return_url)

get_auth_link()

# Make a POST request to exchange the Authorization Code for an Access Token
import json

def get_access_token():
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'User-Agent': 'OAuth gem v0.4.4'}
    AUTH_CODE = 'XXXX'
    ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'
    client_id= 'XXXX'
    client_secret= 'XXXX'
    redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/login'
    PARAM = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'code': AUTH_CODE,
      'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
      'client_id': client_id,
      'client_secret': client_secret}
    response = requests.post(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, data=PARAM, headers=headers, timeout=600)
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
    access_token = data['access_token']
    return access_token

get_access_token()

access_token = 'XXXX'

def get_profile(access_token):
    URL = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me"
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Authorization':'Bearer {}'.format(access_token),'X-Restli-Protocol-Version':'2.0.0'}
    response = requests.get(url=URL, headers=headers)
    print(response.json())

get_profile(access_token)
```

As soon as I change the scope from `r_liteprofile` to `r_basicprofile` I get the an unauthorized_scope_error: r_basicprofile is not authorised for your application. In my developpers page I have the scopes`r_emailaddress`, `r_liteprofile` and `w_member_social` authorised. But only `r_liteprofile` works. From what I understand from the [LinkedIn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api), comments cannot be downloaded?

So the big question really is, can comments be downloaded via API?

Bots or scrapers are not an option as they require explicit permission from LinkedIn, which I do not have.

**Up-date:**  so no illegal solutions please. I knew before I have written this post that they exist.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two legal options to download comments that do not breach LinkedIn's terms and conditions. Both require LinkedIn's permission.

**Option A:** [Comment API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/comments-api?tabs=http)

The [Comment API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/comments-api?tabs=http) is part of the Page Management APIs which in turn is part of the Marketing Developer Program (MDP). LinkedIn describes the application process for its marketing developer program [here](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a527289). It requires filling out a form specifying the use case. Then LinkedIn decides whether to grant access. [These use cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/restricted-use-cases) will be restricted or not approved.

**Option B:** Web crawling and scraping LinkedIn with an exemption (whitelist)
 Exemption process is described [here](https://www.linkedin.com/legal/crawling-terms).

I am going for option A. Let's see if they give me access. I'll up-date the post accordingly.

**Up-date 19/05/2022** 
LinkedIn has granted the permissions for the MDP. It took about 2 weeks.

**Up-date 27/05/2022** 
[Here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mining-social-media-data-using-python-2-make-api-request-wong/) is a great tutorial to get individual posts. Getting company page posts is another [story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242862/linkedin-api-get-company-datas) - [entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965891/linkedin-api-returns-does-not-exist) - so opened a new [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72406550/getting-linkedin-company-shares-python)

Answer (score 0):

I found that login with the [linkedin-api](https://github.com/tomquirk/linkedin-api) by tomquirk was really easy. However, a KeyError was raised when a post does not have any comment. I fixed it in a [fork](https://github.com/bigoulours/linkedin-api) and just submitted a pull request. If you install the fork with `python setup.py install`, following code will get all your posts with comments:

```
from linkedin_api import Linkedin
import getpass

print("Please enter your LinkedIn credentials first (2FA must be disabled)")
username = input("user: ")
password = getpass.getpass('password: ')

api = Linkedin(username, password)

my_public_id = api.get_user_profile()['miniProfile']['publicIdentifier']

my_posts = api.get_profile_posts(public_id=my_public_id)
for post in my_posts:
    post_urn = post['socialDetail']['urn'].rsplit(':', 1)[1]
    print('POST:' + post_urn + '\n')
    comments = api.get_post_comments(post_urn, comment_count=100)
    for comment in comments:
        commenter = comment['commenter']['com.linkedin.voyager.feed.MemberActor']['miniProfile']
        print(f"\t{commenter['firstName']} {commenter['lastName']}: {comment['comment']['values'][0]['value']}\n")
```

Note: this does not use the official API, and according to the README.md:

> This project violates Linkedin's User Agreement Section 8.2, and because of this, Linkedin may (and will) temporarily or permanently ban your account.

However, as long as you scrape comments only from your own account you should be fine.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer!!  I saw the tomquick scraper already (see [this link in my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481272/python-linkedin-api-how-do-i-use-it?rq=1) ) It violates LinkedIn's User agreement. [ReadMe at the bottom](https://github.com/tomquirk/linkedin-api#readme) warns that accounts will be blocked. How many times have you scraped your own comments? Within which time interval? I need a solution that I can use repeatedly.

Comment: I've tested the above code on someone else's profile (I don't post anything there) and have retrieved search results in the past. The only thing that happened (after a high number of searches) is that the amount of search results were limited to 3 until the end of the month (happens with free accounts)

Comment: Dummy profiles for scraping are not a solution for this project. That is why I said in my post that scrapes are not an option. Scraping might work a few times with a dummy profile. Then a new one needs to be created. I suspect that the profile you used popped up on LinkedIn's radar hence they limited the search capacity. Have you continued to scrape after that with the same profile? If yes, how many times per week?  
At the moment your suggestion seems to be a quick fix, but not really a solution to the problem I have.

Comment: I've searched with my personal profile and wasn't blocked at any moment (the 3 results limitation would likely occur in the browser as well and is reset at the beginning of the next month). The limit was triggered after the script visited hundreds (if not thousands) of linkedin pages. So if you only intend to get your own comments (e.g. weekly) it shouldn't be a big deal... Why don't you try with a dummy profile for a start and see how long (if ever) it takes to get banned? You could hard code your public id (see your profile url) in the code I provided

Comment: Tranbi, there is two problems with this a) investing time into something that may break down in 2 or 3 months is not a sustainable use of money.  b) this question relates to my work. Using the thomquick scraper is illegal. Just because I am not caught by LinkedIn does not mean that there won't be consequences from other parties. I really like my job :-) I am not sure how I can spell it out more clearly: no scraper or other illegal solutions please.

Comment: Got it! ;-) from your question it seemed you were trying to get comments from your profile only so I didn't think it was work related. Good luck finding a solution!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244190/discussion-between-simone-and-tranbi).

Comment: Tranbi, found a solution. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/comments-api?tabs=http)